# Cannot import from module inside the same package, from a subpackage

Tags: python

I have the following structure

```
folder/
├─ subfolder/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ script.py
├─ __init__.py
├─ module.py
```

Inside `script.py` I want to import the function `my_function` from `module.py`. I have tried various variants

```py
from ..module import my_function
from ...folder.module import my_function
from .. import module         # and then use module.my_function
from ... import folder.module # and then use folder.module.my_function
```

However, whenever I am in the terminal inside `folder` and run `python3 subfolder/script.py` I get the error

```py
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: `python3 subfolder/script.py` runs `script.py` as a top-level script that _is not associated with a package_. You probably mean to use `python3 -m folder.subfolder.script`, assuming that `folder` is your intended top-level package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: Also, remember that Python imports **do not** navigate your filesystem. Imports are only resolved by searching the Python path. If you want `folder` to be an importable package, it's containing directory must be on the Python path. This is generally done either by installing your project as a distribution package or by relying on having the parent directory of `folder` be your CWD. All modules named in imports inside your package need to follow the package structure. E.g., there is no module named `script`, only one named `folder.subfolder.script`.